# C++ space at start of filepath

Tags: c++, printing, cout

I have a C++ program that should print out the results in the console to be passed as the command line arguments to another program.

The problem I am having is that two of the outputs are being printed as a single string with no space and so are not being taken in as two separate arguments.

Is it possible to add a space to the start of one of the strings to separate the arguments?

This is what the program should be outputting:

```
0 haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:46
1 haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:46
2 haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:47
3 haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:47
```

Instead it is outputting:

```
0haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:46
1haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:46
2haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:47
3haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 2014-10-16T11:00:47
```

These are the strings that should be printed:

```
int eventCount = 0;
string cascadeName = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
string nestedCascadeName = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

I'm printing them using:

```
        std::cout << ("%s", cascadeName);
        std::cout << ("%d", eventCount);
        timeFound();
        std::cout << std::flush;
```

timeFound():

```
int timeFound() {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];
  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  strftime (buffer,80," %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);
  eventCount++;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I get the output to print as expected?

N.B. I've tried adding spaces in both the printing lines but it seems to have no effect. I have also tried putting spaces in the `string` declaration but it results in the program being unable to locate the classifier XML files.

Comment: What command line are you using for passing the output to the other program, and how does it handle its arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the `printf` type language (e.g `'%d'`,`'%s'`, *etc*) with ostreams, you just use `operator<<()` which is overloaded for the types you want to output.

Have `timeFound()` return it's output:

```
std::string timeFound() {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime (buffer,80," %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
    eventCount++;
    return buffer;
}
```

Then you want something more like:

```
std::cout << cascadeName << ' ' << eventCount << ' ' << timeFound() << std::endl;
```

Comment: The only problem is there is a random `0` being printed `1 haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 0 2014-10-16T11:35:44`

Comment: Sorry it was the `return 0;` in `timeFound()`

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just insert some spaces, like this:

```
std::cout << cascadeName << " " << eventCount << " " << timeFound() << std::endl;
```

---

Incidentally:

```
std::cout << ("%s", cascadeName);
```

doesn't do what you think it does - you can't use `printf` style formatting with `std::cout` - all you are doing here is using the comma operator, which discards the `"%s"` and evaluates `cascadeName`, so this is effectively just:

```
std::cout << cascadeName;
```

Comment: I tried that but the second program didn't seem to take them as separate arguments.

Comment: Well that's probably a different problem, but it's hard to say without seeing the second program.

Comment: Gives me something to go on at least.

Comment: OK - one problem at a time. Check the output from your program to make sure the format's correct with the above change. If that looks OK then you probably need to debug your second program - post another question about that if you get stuck.